# How to say if a tree is included in another one?

Tags: python-3.x, tree

I would like to create an alogritmo that allows me to say if a tree is included in another. Thanks to [this site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-binary-tree-is-subtree-of-another-binary-tree/) I managed an algorithm that allows me to know for binary trees, but I would like to generalize it.

```
def isSubtree(T,S):
    '''
    function to say if a tree S is a subtree of another one, T
    '''
    # Base Case
    if S is None:
        return True

    if T is None:
        return True

    # Check the tree with root as current node
    if (areIdentical(T, S)):
        return True

    # IF the tree with root as current node doesn't match
    # then try left and right subtreee one by one
    return isSubtree(T.children, S) or isSubtree(T.children, S) # won't work because we have several children

def areIdentical(root1, root2):
    '''
    function to say if two roots are identical
    '''
    # Base Case
    if root1 is None and root2 is None:
        return True
    if root1 is None or root2 is None:
        return False

    # Check if the data of both roots their and children are the same
    return (root1.data == root2.data and
            areIdentical(root1.children, root2.children)) # Here problem because it won't work for children
```

#### Expectd output

For instance :

```
>>># first tree creation
>>>text = start becoming popular
>>>textSpacy = spacy_nlp(text1)
>>>treeText = nltk_spacy_tree(textSpacy)
>>>t = WordTree(treeText[0])

>>># second tree creation
>>>question = When did Beyonce start becoming popular?
>>>questionSpacy = spacy_nlp(question)
>>>treeQuestion = nltk_spacy_tree(questionSpacy)
>>>q = WordTree(treeQuestion[0])

>>># tree comparison
>>>isSubtree(t,q)
True
```

---

In case this may be useful, here is the `WordTree` class that I used:

```
class WordTree:
    '''Tree for spaCy dependency parsing array'''
    def __init__(self, tree, is_subtree=False):
        """
        Construct a new 'WordTree' object.

        :param array: The array contening the dependency
        :param parent: The parent of the array if exists
        :return: returns nothing
        """
        self.parent = []
        self.children = []
        self.data = tree.label().split('_')[0] # the first element of the tree # We are going to add the synonyms as well.

        for subtree in tree:
            if type(subtree) == Tree:
                # Iterate through the depth of the subtree.
                t = WordTree(subtree, True)
                t.parent=tree.label().split('_')[0]
            elif type(subtree) == str:
                surface_form = subtree.split('_')[0]
                self.children.append(surface_form)
```

It works very well with trees made with Spacy phrases.

```
question = "When did Beyonce start becoming popular?"
questionSpacy = spacy_nlp(question)
treeQuestion = nltk_spacy_tree(questionSpacy)
t = WordTree(treeQuestion[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate over all the children of `T`, and if `S` is a subtree of any of the children of `T`, then `S` is a subtree of `T`. Also, you should return `False` when `T` is `None` because it means that you are already at a leaf of `T` and `S` is still not found to be a subtree:

```
def isSubtree(T,S):
    if S is None:
        return True
    if T is None:
        return False
    if areIdentical(T, S):
        return True
    return any(isSubtree(c, S) for c in T.children)
```